# Qt, CMake, Visual Studio and Q_OBJECT in cpp files

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake, qobject

I'm developing a large project using Qt 4.6, CMake 2.8 and Visual Studio 2008 for the Windows platform.

As far the build system goes, it's all standard stuff: I'm using CMake's `QT4_WRAP_CPP` macro to generate moc files from header files, which are then linked into the final executable in the `add_executable` command. Everything is working as expected.

The only restriction with this setup is that I can't define widgets or helper using   `Q_OBJECT` in *.cpp* files. This would be very convenient for small, context-specific helpers classes that should appear right next to where they're used.

I tried to pass the whole list of source files (both *.h* and *.cpp*) to `QT4_WRAP_CPP`, instead of just the header files, but that doesn't work (linking fails because some moc-related symbols are undefined).

I think the problem is that, for a given pair of files *foo.h* and *foo.cpp*, the `QT4_WRAP_CPP` macro will generate the same moc file (*moc_foo.cxx*) in the same directory, and obviously that means the first file will be overwritten by the second one, and as a result symbols will be missing at link-time.

Is there a way to fix or work around that problem? For instance, I tried to add a specific rule for *foo.cpp* of the form

```
QT4_GENERATE_MOC(directory/foo.cpp directory/foo.moc)
```

and then add

```
#include "foo.moc"
```

at the end of *foo.cpp*. I think this ought to work, but alas Visual Studio only allows one build rule per file, and *.cpp* files already have a build rule (compilation to object file), so this approach doesn't work, at least with Visual Studio.

Another idea that I had was to create a new macro, say `QT4_WRAP_CPP_WITH_PREFIX`, based on `QT4_WRAP_CPP` (which is defined in *share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Qt4Macros.cmake*), that would take an additional prefix argument and would add this prefix to the generated moc files. That way, I would call `QT4_WRAP_CPP_WITH_PREFIX` twice, once for *.h* files and once for *.cpp* files, with different prefixes. What I just dislike about this approach is that I'd be messing with the internals of CMake's Qt support, instead of using the public API.

Any better idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this bit: "The only restriction with this setup is that I can't define widgets or helper using Q_OBJECT in .cpp files." You shouldn't ever need to run MOC on anything except header files?

Comment: I find it convenient to occasionnally define a small helper class in a .cpp file, and not expose it outside of this .cpp file.  For this I need to be able to run MOC on .cpp files. The `QT4_WRAP_CPP_WITH_PREFIX` macro approach outlined in my post works like a charm.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune - did you ever come up with a solution for this? Even for something this simple: #include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>

#include <iostream>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
};

int main(int, char*[])
{

  MyClass myClass;

  return 0;
}

I can't figure out how to MOC it since it is in a cpp file (and I get the vtable errors when trying to build it normally).

Comment: @DavidDoria My solution may lack in elegance but it works: I'm simply moc'ing all files (including .cpp files) [1], and in those cpp files that require moc'ing, I include the generated moc file [2]. [1]: https://github.com/jupiter-jazz/appleseed/blob/master/src/appleseed.studio/CMakeLists.txt#L302 [2]: https://github.com/jupiter-jazz/appleseed/blob/ef5b9b0a4e4e5bc3fb359a35ce621ec3677f0b94/src/appleseed.studio/mainwindow/project/entityeditorwindow.cpp#L528

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of CMake have "automoc" which worked like a charm for me:
http://blogs.kde.org/2011/11/01/cool-new-stuff-cmake-286-automoc

Simply add in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC TRUE)
```

and then in the cpp (e.g. example.cpp) file:

```
#include "example.moc"
```

(the *.moc must match the cpp file's name).

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the documentation "Using the MOC" (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.1/moc.html), you'd only need to import "foo.moc" at the end of your implementation file. As you can not tweak the build rules correspondingly, try to export a .pro file and apply the build rule as suggested by the nokia document.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @DavidDoria, since I cannot make a comment to his response: Recent versions of CMake have changed the syntax slightly (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html#including-header-moc-files-in-sources)):

`#include <moc_<header_base>.cpp> // or #include "moc_<header_base>.cpp"`